# Spring + bootstrap + bootstrap tags + typeahead + multiple datasets

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, tags, typeahead

I trying to build a Spring app using bootstrap with search input field using bootstrap tags and typeahead but with multiple datasets.
Right now I am able to do it with single datasets and it looks like : 
[single dataset input field with tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp71p.png)

but I want to have a multpile datasets:
[multiple datasets input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzl0K.png)
 (multiple datasets example from typeahead.js/examples/ )

Of course I want this to work with Tags like I showed for single dataset.
But If I just use code from the above example for multiple datasets it doesn't work.
At the moment I have working code for single dataset with tags, code below:

hello.jsp

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/new/bootstrap-3.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <!--Tags Input CSS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/new/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div>
   <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City Name">
  </div>
 
  <!--JQuery JS-->
  <script src="resources/new/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  
  <!--Bootstrap JS-->
  <script src="resources/new/bootstrap-3.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <!--Typeahead JS-->
  <script src="resources/new/typeahead/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
  
  <!--Tags Input JS-->
  <script src="resources/new/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
  
  <!--Custom JS-->
  <script src="resources/new/custom.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

custom.js

```js
/**
 * 
 */


var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];


var miasta = ['Wroclaw','Poznan','Gdynia'];

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //init Tags Input
            $('#city').tagsinput({
                minLength: 0,
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                typeahead: {
                 source: states,
                }
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Like you can see in hello.jsp file I using :

- jQuery 1.11.2
- Bootstrap 3.3.2
- Typeahead 2.3.2
- bootstrap-tagsinput v0.5.0

Do you have idea how I can connect above Bootstrap Tags with Typeahead with mutliple datasets ? I suppose that I probably used wrong version of bootstrap tags or typeahead or something else and this is the cause of the problem. If yes could you please say me which versions are compatibile? or how to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to add the different sets of data in an array inside the typeahead property of the tagsinput initializer object, like this:

```
var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];


var miasta = ['Wroclaw','Poznan','Gdynia'];

(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //init Tags Input
            $('#city').tagsinput({
                typeahead: [{
                    minLength: 1,
                    hint: false,
                    highlight: true
                },[{
                    source: states
                }, {
                    source: miasta
                }]]
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Note that the properties you put in your code snippet are properties of one of the elements of the typeahead array, not a property of the tagsinput object. Also note how the different sources are encapsulated in its own object, and each of these objects are part of an array, which is an element of the typeahead array. It's a bit confusing, but that's how the tagsinput library integrates the typeahead one.